# dynamic URI comma separated for request mapping param spring boot

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular, spring, spring-boot

```
@DeleteMapping(path = "delete/{settingId:[\\d]+}/{userId:[\\d]+}")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<String>> deleteSettingById(
        @PathVariable Integer[] settingId,)
```

I want to test in postman like this
http://localhost:9994/setting/delete/54793685,54793685/6
how to change settingId to accept comma separated ids from angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create POJO with a custom deserializer.

```
public class SettingIds {
    private int[] ids;
    // getter,setter,constructor
}
```

The deserializer needs to extend `PropertyEditorSupport`:

```
@Component
public class SettingIdsDeserializer extends PropertyEditorSupport {

  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      String[] splitEntry = text.split(",");
      int[] idArray = Stream.of(splitEntry).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
      setValue(new SettingIds(idArray));
  }
}
```

Then you wire in the deserializer to your controller and register it with the init binder annotation:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(SettingIds.class, settingIdsDeserializer);
}
```

Now your endpoint could look like:

```
  @DeleteMapping(path = "delete/{settingIds:[\\d]+}/{userId:[\\d]+}")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<String>> deleteSettingById(
    @PathVariable SettingIds settingIds)
```